# Python import error when I just 'import numpy'

Tags: python, numpy

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Python3, numpy, pandas.
When I just entered 'import numpy', the following error came out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regression1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 3093, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _methods
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 158, in <module>
    _NDARRAY_ARRAY_FUNCTION = mu.ndarray.__array_function__
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

Also When I just entered 'import pandas', the same error appeared. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using virtual env? If yes, make sure you source to it.

Comment: How did you launch python? If you just typed `python` in bash, you probably launched the built-in python 2 implementation. Alternatively, maybe you launched python3 but installed numpy tp python two by calling `pip numpy` instead of `pip3 numpy`. Try `pip list | grep numpy` and `pip3 list | grep numpy` to see which you've installed it to. Lastly, if you're working with numpy, you should strongly consider installing python3 via Anaconda rather than doing it your self. And then use virtual environment (like `conda env`) as others are recommending.

Comment: How did you install Python, NumPy, Pandas? Please provide all details. All we can tell from your error log: you are using Python 3.5 and a "user" install (i.e. in `$HOME/.local`) of NumPy. Importing NumPy errors, which means that pandas won't run anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **not using** virtual environment, try to reinstall the libraries using:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy pandas --user --force-reinstall
```

If you are **using** virtual environment, first you need to activate it before installing the libraries. This may be the case for example if you are using PyCharm to write your scripts (it suggests to make one when you create new project). If this is the case, first go to the folder with your project and activate the virtual environment using:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

If your virtual environment has a different name than `venv`, use that name instead.

Once it's activated, install the libraries using:

```
python -m pip install numpy pandas --force-reinstall
```

Comment: The installs are local, so add `--user` to the pip invocation in absence of venv.

Answer (score 0):

try to enter the following in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

I think you just got the lib for the wrong version of python

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?

Comment: I am using numpy (1.15.4)

Comment: I may be wrong but try to upgrade your numpy version with pip3

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs if the numpy is not correctly installed in the designated folder.

The following works for Python 3 users
Go to your python directory in cmd and run the following command:

```
py -3 -m pip install numpy
```

I hope this works for you too!!